# Can a normal vector be derived if incident vector, refracted vector and ratio of indices of refraction are known?

Tags: geometry

Given the following information:

1. Incident vector $\underline{\widehat i}$
2. Refracted vector $\underline{\widehat o}$
3. Ratio of indices of refraction $\frac{n_1}{n_2}$

Can we derive normal $\underline{\widehat n}$?

Hint:

1. The solution to the 3D case can be derived if we have the solution to the 2D case, so here let's just concentrate on that.
2. The solution to the 2D case can be known by deriving either $\theta_1$ or $\theta_2$.

[image: Diagram of refractive optics]

Answer (score 1):

From Snell's law,

$ n_1 \sin \theta_1 = n_2 \sin \theta_2 $

So that $ \sin \theta_2 = r \sin \theta_1 $, where $r = \dfrac{n_1}{n_2} $

Also, the acute angle between the incident unit vector $\hat{u_1} = \hat{i}$ and the refracted unit vector $\hat{u_2} = \hat{o} $ is given by

$ \phi = \cos^{-1} ( \hat{u_1} \cdot \hat{u_2} ) $

And we have

$ \phi =  \theta_2  - \theta_1  $

Note that $\theta_2 \gt \theta_1 $ because $n_1 \gt n_2$.

Hence,

$ \cos \phi = \hat{u_1} \cdot \hat{u_2} =  =  \cos(\theta_1 - \theta_2) = sin(\theta_1) \sin(\theta_2) + \cos (\theta_1) \cos (\theta_2) $

Since $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are less than $90^\circ$ then

$ \cos \theta_1 = \sqrt{ 1 - \sin^2 \theta_1 } $

$ \cos \theta_2 = \sqrt{ 1 - \sin^2 \theta_2 } = \sqrt{1 - r^2 \sin^2 \theta_1 } $

If $s =\sin \theta_1 $ then

$\cos \phi =  \bigg((1 - s^2)(1 - r^2 s^2)\bigg)^{1/2}  + r s^2 $

Hence,

$ \bigg((1 - s^2) (1 - r^2 s^2 ) \bigg)^{1/2} =  \cos \phi - r s^2 $

Squaring, and letting $u = s^2 $, then

$ (1 - u)(1 - r^2 u) = \cos^2 \phi + r^2 u^2 - 2 r \cos \phi u $

Cancelling $r^2 u^2 $ on both sides of the equation,

$ 1 - (1 + r^2) u = \cos^2 \phi -  2 r \cos \phi u $

Hence,

$ u = \dfrac{ \sin^2 \phi } {- 2 r \cos \phi + 1 + r^2 } $

Hence,

$ \theta_1 = \sin^{-1} \bigg( \dfrac{\sin \phi } {\sqrt{ -2 r \cos \phi + 1 + r^2 }} \bigg) $

and it follows that

$ \theta_2 = \sin^{-1} r \sin \theta_1 $

Now that we have $\theta_1$, and $\theta_2$ we need the orientation of the unit normal $\hat{n}$.  So let

$ \hat{n} = (n_x, n_y) = (\cos \psi, \sin \psi) $

Then using the dot product with $\hat{i}$ and also with $\hat{o}$, we get

$ \hat{i} \cdot \hat{n} = \cos \theta_1 = i_x \cos \psi + i_y \sin \psi $

and

$ \hat{o} \cdot \hat{n} = \cos \theta_2 = o_x \cos \psi + o_y \sin \psi $

These are two linear equations in $\cos \psi$ and $\sin \psi$ which can be readily solved.  Upon solving them, we will have the value of $\cos \psi$ and $\sin \psi$, so $\psi $ can be uniquely determined.

This gives the direction of the normal vector.